# SWI-Prolog is using oodles of memory at startup

Tags: memory, prolog, swi-prolog

SWI-Prolog has suddenly become unusable for me for unknown reasons.

When I run SWI-Prolog, it very rapidly starts consuming all available memory (many GB) until it freezes my laptop.

I notice that my ~/.pl-history file was several GB in size, so I tried removing it and trying again. Upon restarting SWI-Prolog, it rapidly jumped back to several GB in size.

I'm not sure how to debug this issue, and haven't been able to find other reports of this behavior.

Comment: Does the same thing happens when you start SWI-Prolog using `swipl -f none` ?

Comment: No! Just tried that, didn't happen. But now it's not happening *either* way, whereas it was previously happening consistently. /confused